# $2 ^ {\sin ^ 2x}\cos x = 1$

Tags: trigonometry

An equation I find to be difficult. $$2 ^ {\sin ^ 2x}\cos x = 1$$. I have tried proving that $\frac{1}{\cos x}$ and $2 ^ {\sin ^ 2x}$ have different monotonies, but they do not. The substitution $\cos x = a$ would make the equation $2 ^ {1 - a ^ 2} a = 1$, but I cannot continue with this either.

One of my friends found a solution. If we let $sin ^ 2 \ x = a$, and square the equation, we get $2 ^ {\frac{2}{x}}(1 - \frac{1}{x}) = 1$. Multiply it with $x$ and, then raise it to the power of x: $4(x - 1) ^ x = x ^ x$, so $$(\frac{x}{x - 1}) ^ x = 4$$

Now, it is quite easy to prove $(\frac{x - 1}{x}) ^ x$ is strictly increasing. So
$(\frac{x - 1}{x}) ^ x = \frac {1}{4}$ has only one solution, which is $x = 2$.
Then, $sin ^ 2 x = 2$, so $x = \frac{\pi}{4} + 2k\pi, \ k \in Z $, since $2k\pi$ is the period.

Comment: Do you need to find one solution or all solutions ?

Comment: There are only few combinations of $(2^{\sin x})$ and $(\cos x)$ to be equal to $1$

Comment: @Surb I am supposed to find all solutions. But, if a is a solution, $a + 2k \pi$ will also be a solution.

Comment: @DatBoi Nice reasoning, but $2^{\sin^2 x}$ ranges between $2^0$ and $2^1$, and $\cos x$ ranges between $0$ and $1$. Therefore $2^{\sin x}, \cos x$ are not necessarily equal to $1$: you could have $(\frac{1}{2}, 2)$ for example.

Comment: You can answer your own question. The solution looks OK, except you must also consider the case $x=0$ (which happens to be a solution as well)

Answer (score 1):

One graphic approach.
Let me change $x$ by $t$.

Using paramtrical equation, $x=\sin t,\, y=\cos t$ is the unit circle.

But then $2^{\sin^2 t}\cos t=1$ becames $2^{x^2} y=1$ which means $y=2^{-x^2}$.

So if you plot the function $y=2`{-x^2}$ and look for intersections with the unit circle, you'll get that there are 3 solutions: 1 is the point $(0,1)$ and the other two solutions cannot be solved analitically

[image]

Finally, go back and set $(\sin t,\cos t)=(0,1)\Rightarrow t=0+2k\pi$, and the same for the other two points.

EDIT:

That is what Mathematica says:
$$\left\{\{x\to 0\},\left\{x\to \fbox{$-\frac{\sqrt{W_{c_1}\left(-\frac{\log (2)}{2}\right)+2
   \log (2)}}{\sqrt{2 \log (2)}}\text{ if }c_1\in \mathbb{Z}$}\right\},\left\{x\to
   \fbox{$\frac{\sqrt{W_{c_1}\left(-\frac{\log (2)}{2}\right)+2 \log (2)}}{\sqrt{2 \log
   (2)}}\text{ if }c_1\in \mathbb{Z}$}\right\}\right\}$$